# App crashes on ActionBar with Theme.Appcompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, themes, android-appcompat

I'm using [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) that need a Theme.AppCompat to work.
I need to use ActionBar to display the back navigation button, so I've created a parent theme 'AppCompatC' in which I've declared windowActioBar = true:

```
<style name="AppCompatC" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item> 
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item> 
    <item name="logo">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_action_previous_item</item>
</style>
```

If I launch the application, the activity loads the ActionBar but If I call it from code too (cause I need to see the launcher icon in the bar), a java.lang.NullPointerException is launched on actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

```
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        // Enabling Up / Back navigation
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

In the Manifest I've defined:

```
        android:theme="@style/AppCompatC"
        android:parentActivityName=".Launcher"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getSupportActionBar()` with support library.
Moreover, your activity should extend `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`, not `android.app.Activity`

Comment: I'm already extending android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity. What about the getSupportActionBar() ? I've tried ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); and I've: Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.support.v7.app.ActionBar to android.app.ActionBar

Comment: Obviously because you should use ActionBar from the support library (`android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how can I show the app icon on it ?

Comment: if `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` then app icon is replaced with Up icon. Please refer to documentation for more information about ActionBar http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html